# Why does Visual Studio 2015 report missing headers when building Python modules from source?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, anaconda

I'm attempting to install the scikits.samplerate library for Python on Windows 10. My Python version is 3.5.1, installed with the Anaconda distribution, using the MSVC 14.0 compiler. I have compiled and linked the necessary libsamplerate files. However, when I go to install the module with the command

```
python setup.py install
```

I'm getting missing header file errors. Initially, I have

```
Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h': No such file or directory
```

but this is not the only header missing. There are other basics like stdlib.h and io.h also.

I guess my question is whether there is something wrong with my installation of Visual Studio 2015? I had Visual Studio 2013 installed already, so has that somehow messed with things? I'm aware of the move to the Universal CRT, but the include directory to which the compile command is pointing doesn't actually exist:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10586.0\ucrt
```

I have two other ucrt include directories, but they are found under the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt
```

Adding these as include directories and proceeding with the scikits.samplerate install results in

```
python.exe has stopped working
```

I'm really out of ideas here, and I'd really like to get this library up and running.

Comment: Have you googled this? Does this apply? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/86bc577b-528c-469c-a506-15383a44c111/missing-corecrth-from-the-default-include-folder-for-vs215?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: Having the same problem on Windows 10. On Windows 7 works fine -.-

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is called with:

```
-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt
```

But you have 2 `ucrt` folders (somewhere else):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt
```

So you have to copy the folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt
to
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt
```

And copy the libs as well:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt
to
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.14393.0\ucrt
```